# How to kick off Linux script in AKS from Web App (AZURE) on-demand

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-webapps

Given that I have a 24x7 `AKS` Cluster on AZURE, for which afaik Kubernetes cannot stop/pause a pod and then resume it standardly,

- with, in my case, a small Container in a Pod, and for that Pod it can be sidelined via `--replicas=0`,

  - then, how can I, on-demand, best kick off a LINIX script packaged in that Pod/Container which may be not running,

    - from an AZURE Web App?

I thought using `ssh` should work, after first upscaling the pod to 1 replica. Is this correct?

I am curious if there are simple `http` calls in AZURE to do this. I see CLI and Powershell to start/stop AKS cluster, but that is different of course.

Comment: what's the nature of your script? is it a service or something that acts like a job?

Comment: A batch job gathering data on the AZURE LZ and then calling a Solver for Work Force optimization - writing that to a local DB. Essential I need to ramp up the pod if idle and then call a nohup script to run the above.

Comment: Kubernetes jobs are not relevant here?

Comment: We run our batch jobs on AKS, that's a given

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. @Fnaxiom

Comment: Have you considered using Kubernetes clients? I think it is safer than using ssh. Http is the way to reach the api server. eg:  https://github.com/kubernetes-client. They have many example on how to run pods and other kube tasks.

Comment: Is this an answer? We have Web Apps not in containers. We have AKS for batch jobs and some stateful workarounds with Web Apps in AZURE. I will read now.

Comment: @Fnaxiom  that link is a little too foreign to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249013/discussion-between-fnaxiom-and-thebluephantom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interact remotely with AKS by different methods. The key here is to use the control plane API to deploy your kubernetes resource programmatically (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) .

In order to do that, you should use client libraries that enable that kind of access. Many examples can be found here for different programming languages:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client

`ssh` is not really recommended since that is sort of a god access to the cluster and its usage is not meant for your purpose.

Comment: Having read it, I realize a background Web Service can be used as well in conjunction with an AZURE Function for once daily schedule and via a Web Service from Angular on-demand.